# Need Android background service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I am building an Android application.
I am trying to do a running app. this means I will need a background service running and counting my GPS data and report that to the activity.

But - I want the activity to be able to send actions to this service too (Start, Stop , etc).

I have struggled with a few methods of doing this 2-way service<->activity communications.

Any reference? what is the best approach to do that?

Thanks

Comment: did you try Broadcast service??

Comment: I did it with IntentService. what is the diff?

Comment: IntentService is a thread to perform your task, Broadcast is one of the method your task can "tell" your activity to do update, the complete keyword to Google for is "LocalBroadcastManager".

Comment: You can use broadcast receiver to communicate between service and activity, I usually do the same. But, recently I have came across otto and EventBus. I haven't used these but, read good things about these libraries. You can take a look into it.

Comment: This may not be what you had in mind, but an idea may be to use an [`EventBus`](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to communicate between services and activities. This has been becoming increasing popular mostly because working with `Services` can be tricky in Android. Additionally it allows you to use one services with multiple activities easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try service bind mechanism?

You can create service for collecting GPS data (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), start it on application startup (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService), bind this service on starting your activity and use binder object for transferring data between the service and activity (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), unbind on closing your activity and service will continue working on background.

In this model, your service will work always and will transfer data when it needed.

Answer (score 0):

Binding might be an overkill when you deal with the same process. I would recommend using Otto from Square as an event bus mechanism to post events to your service and vice versa.

If you dont want to add a library to your project then consider using the `LocalBroadcastManager` that is part of the support library.

Comment: I am using that. but in onCreate I have startService which restarts my service.